# cmp is returning two different results based on evaluation method

Tags: python, functional-programming, built-in

So I'm trying to get some practice passing functions and keywords as arguments in python and I'm getting a strange result. I have the following code:

```
def myeval(f, *args, **kwargs):
    return f(*args, **kwargs)

def tester(x = 0, y = 0):
    return cmp(x,y)
```

And then when I do some testing, strange things happen:

```
>>> cmp(1,10)
    -1
>>> tester(1,10)
    -1
>>> tester(x=1, y=10)
    -1
```

Which is expected. BUT:

```
>>> myeval(tester, {"x":1, "y":10})
    1
```

Why is this different? Shouldn't myeval also return -1? Is there something weird going on behind the scenes with the evaluation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do `myeval(tester, **{"x":1, "y":10})`.

As `myeval(tester, {"x":1, "y":10})` results in `args` being `[{"x":1, "y":10}]` rather than `kwargs` being `{"x":1, "y":10}` as desired.

Or define your function as say:

```
def myeval(f, args, kwargs):
```

And then call it as:

```
myeval(tester, [], {"x":1, "y":10})
```

Terminology wise what you have there is an `apply` not an `eval`.

Comment: Great, thanks so much! On a related note, can you refer me to any good resources specifically about the difference between `apply` and `eval` ?